# .join() function does not work properly in the map function

Tags: javascript, iteration

I am trying to traverse an object using map function to the following format:

```
Name: Hong Kong
TopLevelDomain: .hk
Alpha2Code: HK
Alpha3Code: HKG
CallingCodes: 852
Capital: City of Victoria
AltSpellings: HK, 香港
Region: Asia
Subregion: Eastern Asia
Population: 7324300
Latlng: 22.25, 114.16666666
```

from the below JavaScript object:

```
const object = {
    "name": "Hong Kong",
    "topLevelDomain": [
        ".hk"
    ],
    "alpha2Code": "HK",
    "alpha3Code": "HKG",
    "callingCodes": [
        "852"
    ],
    "capital": "City of Victoria",
    "altSpellings": [
        "HK",
        "香港"
    ],
    "region": "Asia",
    "subregion": "Eastern Asia",
    "population": 7324300,
    "latlng": [
        22.25,
        114.16666666
    ],
    "demonym": "Chinese",
    "area": 1104.0,
    "gini": 53.3,
    "timezones": [
        "UTC+08:00"
    ],
    "borders": [
        "CHN"
    ],
    "nativeName": "香港",
    "numericCode": "344",
    "currencies": [
        {
            "code": "HKD",
            "name": "Hong Kong dollar",
            "symbol": "$"
        }
    ]
};
```

My attempt is:

```js
const object = { "name": "Hong Kong", "topLevelDomain": [ ".hk" ], "alpha2Code": "HK", "alpha3Code": "HKG", "callingCodes": [ "852" ], "capital": "City of Victoria", "altSpellings": [ "HK", "香港" ], "region": "Asia", "subregion": "Eastern Asia", "population": 7324300, "latlng": [ 22.25, 114.16666666 ], "demonym": "Chinese", "area": 1104.0, "gini": 53.3, "timezones": [ "UTC+08:00" ], "borders": [ "CHN" ], "nativeName": "香港", "numericCode": "344", "currencies": [ { "code": "HKD", "name": "Hong Kong dollar", "symbol": "$" } ] };
let display = [];
let print = Object.keys(object).map(function(elem){
    if(object[elem] == 0 || object[elem] ==""){
        display = "N/A";
    } else if (typeof object[elem] =='object'){
        display = object[elem].join(", ") ;
    } else {
        display = object[elem];        
    }
    return `${elem.charAt(0).toUpperCase()}${elem.slice(1)}: ${display}`;
})
console.log(print.join('\n'));
```

However, an error was shown up that, and I have no idea how to deal with it. As far as i know that .join() can be used for joining element of an array. Any idea?

```
TypeError: object[elem].join is not a function
```

Comment: Given your sample data, your code should ([and **does**](https://jsfiddle.net/hqcdLjxr/)) work fine. The dataset provided includes only arrays and strings.

Comment: Alana, the whole approach seems wrong to be honest, although @vipulpatel is correct. `object[elem]' is referring to a property on the object. If it is not an array then it will fail.

Comment: @MauriceMeyer My expected output is as shown in the first block

Comment: @Tyler Roper, is right. Running your code in Chrome console works fine.

Comment: (Noting that `currencies` won't work with the given code, anyway.)

Comment: @Alana Your code, as you've shown, has no issues (aside from `currencies` being stringified to `[Object object]`). Please share your *actual* data. As pointed out above, you'd be better off checking *specifically* for an array before joining, *not* a generic "object".

Comment: @Tyler Roper yes i agree with you. With given data set its fine but better to check type as Array. As its failing means Alan has data with strings, arrays and object as well. Or there is no reason, Js would throw this error. Please provide full data set

Comment: @TylerRoper thz for answering, all the data set is the ```object``` and i have to make it the same as in the first block, I am still working on the code.... havent done yet, any suggestion to deal with the [object object] please?

Answer (score 1):

Since you have nested objects.
object[elem].join does not work join is an array function and it will only work with Array. Like below

```
"currencies": [
        {
            "code": "HKD",
            "name": "Hong Kong dollar",
            "symbol": "$"
        }
    ]
```

You will need one more if for Arrays and will need to use a recursive function when there is a nested object

```
function print(object) {
  let objMap= Object.keys(object).map(function(elem){
    if(object[elem] == 0 || object[elem] ==""){
        display = "N/A";
    } else if (object[elem].constructor === Array){
        display = object[elem].join(", ") ;
    } else if (typeof object[elem] =='object'){
        display = print(object[elem]);
    } else {
        display = object[elem];        
    }
    return `${elem.charAt(0).toUpperCase()}${elem.slice(1)}: ${display}`;
  });
  console.log(objMap.join('\n'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're code works fine. All arrays are objects in javascript so typeof can be unhelpful.

.join is an array method and to ensure that is being run on a valid array I would use Array.isArray() instead of using typeof.

Array.isArray() returns true if the value passed in is an Array and false if not.

I agree with Shashi above, when dealing with nesting objects/arrays.

A simple while loop would work when you have to evaluate which data type you are working with.